# Overtime as an engineer in a non-engineering position

Tags: canada, overtime

I think this is a fairly simple question, but I can't find an answer since it seems very niche.

I have a degree in engineering. I have a salaried position in which I am working more than 44 hours per week, I am not a manager.

My job title does not have engineer in it. There are employees with the exact same job title that do not have an engineering degree.

Am I entitled to overtime pay? Or does the iron ring cast a compensation barrier around my existence?

At the moment, I'm mostly asking for the knowledge and I don't plan to pursue overtime pay (despite what I assume will be input against this in comments/answers).

Comment: Thank you for specifying the location in your question! It's highly relevant in this case. In the US, whether you'd be out of luck would probably depend on the job title or nature of the work you're actually doing. (https://webapps.dol.gov/elaws/elg/minwage.htm#who)

Comment: What is "the iron ring"?

Comment: Canadian engineers traditionally wear an iron ring.

Comment: `Am I entitled to overtime pay?` - Only the laws that govern this kind of thing in your particular State/Province/Country can tell you that. You need to research what laws are applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it is outlined in your contract.

If it is not, then I don't see any harm in asking Human Resources/ your Contracting company (if you are a contractor).Your company may have specific guidelines when applying overtime (needs approval from upper management before performing OT, etc.)

I also looked at your position, a "Services Integration Developer". I am positive that you are entitled to an [Overtime.](http://www.workershelp.ca/overtime.asp) Unless there's something specified in your contract. Again, I would simply inquire with the personnel responsible if you're not sure.

Just be sure that when you do file for overtime, make sure your time-tracking is accurate. Always provide a record of your overtime and tasks you were doing.